# Shopify GraphQL API - How to fetch products by exact tag?

Tags: graphql, shopify-api

I have two tags in my store, "summer" and "summer time sadness", and I want to fetch all products with GraphQL API, which has only the tag "summer".

I am sending the following query

```
{
  products(first: 250, after: null, query: "tag:summer") {
    nodes {
      title
      legacyResourceId
      tags
    }
  }
}
```

And I am getting the following result.

```
{
    "data": {
        "products": {
            "nodes": [
                {
                    "title": "Product10106",
                    "legacyResourceId": "8419585753378",
                    "tags": [
                        "summer time sadness"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "title": "Product10090",
                    "legacyResourceId": "8419586375970",
                    "tags": [
                        "summer"
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "extensions": {
        "cost": {
            "requestedQueryCost": 252,
            "actualQueryCost": 3,
            "throttleStatus": {
                "maximumAvailable": 1000.0,
                "currentlyAvailable": 997,
                "restoreRate": 50.0
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Based on docs, it shouldn't be default behaviour unless I do "tag:summer*".
Not sure if this is a bug or if I am doing something wrong here.

Comment: Apparently for tag is different (product title works as expected).I couldn't find a way to make it work with tags (tried: `'`, `\"`). Not sure you can do it